# Conclusion dependency of Z-test and t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, z-test

- When i use t-test using standard deviation which is equal to $5$ which is sample
  standard deviation. I get P-value for which i have to reject
  null-hypothesis but when i use z-test assuming that the population
  standard deviation is known and that is also equal to $5$ then i get
  different P-values and i can reject the null-hypothesis.I don't understand why is there difference?

Comment: How is there a difference between can reject and have to reject?  Also what is your sample size? In large samples the z test and t test are almost the same.

Comment: sample size is 25 , i can reject null-hypothesis that two means are equal with t-test but not with z-test :(

Comment: What you say is not mathematically possible: when the data SD and the assumed SD are the same (i.e., $5$) then the z and t statistics will be the same.  Since all $t$ distributions have longer tails than the Normal distribution used for the z statistic, the p-value for the t-test must be *larger* than the p-value for the z test.  It will be essential, then, for you to provide more details of your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the population standard deviation, you can think of it as an extra piece of information that allows you to reject the null more easily. On the other hand, if you are using the sample standard deviation, you have to account for the uncertainity of this estimate. Therefore you will need to see more extreme evidence to reject the null.

Graphically, you can see what the effect of estimating the standard deviation is. If you have a small sample size, the distribution of your test statistic will have heavier tails (relative to the standard normal distribution; represented by the black cuve below). This means that if your sample size is small, and your t-statistic is identical to your z-statistic, you might not be able to reject the null, since your p-value will be larger. On the other hand, a very large sample size should mean there is little difference in the p-values.

[image: t-dist]
Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Student_t_pdf.svg).